# Как масштабировать фон в сетке Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, bootstrap, grid

Делаю [свою первую страницу](http://test5874.atwebpages.com/) на сетке бутстрап и столкнулся с проблемой. Основное фото я сделал фоном к `<header>` и поместил в него лого, меню, подпись и кнопку. Но при масштабировании страницы фон обрезается по высоте. Пришлось задать ему `min-height` в медиа-запросах. Все бы ничего, но в промежуточных точках расстояние между `<header>` и блоком под ним становится слишком большим. Как это исправить?
[image: Должно получиться примерно так]

Comment: я тоже делал этот шаблон. [зацените](https://miptleha.github.io/sample-sites/freelancer/) не могу сказать, лучше или хуже... но ваша страница ведет себя как-то странно при изменении размера окна. во-первых я не использовал бутстрап (все на базовых флеках сверстал), а во-вторых посмотрел, как этот шаблон делает [профессионал](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ie0thPtYFGw&t=1s)

Comment: знаю что странно, это потому что он не закончен и из-за описанной выше проблемы. я хотел сделать его именно на сетке бутстрап. ваша страница при сжатии тоже ведет себя не очень корректно. примерно после 700px появляется пустое пространство справа. дело в блоке "our team". он не сжимается при таком размере экрана. как вариант можно использовать свойство flex-wrap со значением wrap для переноса на новую строку

Comment: да, спасибо за замечание. надо будет поправить, напишу себе issue :) бутстрап - неплохая сетка, очень люблю ее, сайты не выглядят убого с ней. но в данном случае, от бутстрапа тут практически ничего нет. но раз уж требование с бутстрапом... можно и его вставить и по минимому от него использовать. конкретно по вашей проблеме: 1) у header нужно выставить height:100vh (в этом смысл шаблона, что он показывает картинку на весь экран) 2) у вас штук 5 мест с min-heigh, как убрал их все, сразу пропал разрыв между header и main

Comment: Да, проблему с разрывом уже решил. Глупо было делать min-height. Лоуренс голова руками апреля не даёт)